# ASP.NET Basic Authentication for MIME Type files (None .aspx files)

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, mime-types, basic-authentication

I have to authenticate users (**Basic Authentication**) for accessing a **None .aspx** file against a datasource. I found articles and did it for **.aspx** files but as soon as I try to use it for my file **by adding file extention to IIS as a MIME or Compressed type file, the authentication windows keeps showing and dones't stop.

What Should I do?

```
P.S.1. I cannot change the authentication method with form auth or something else.
P.S.2. I cannot change my file type with ".aspx"
P.S.3. URL Re-Writing didn't solve the problem
P.S.4. I added handler to web.config to show the IIS that the new file extention is a script
    <handlers>
        <add name="NEW FORMAT" path="*.NXX" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule"
        scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
        resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location directive to constraint the access for the actual file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx

And add the mime type if you really need it:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

!
Also you can create an ashx file to help you transmit all the files you require, adding a little more overhead but can provide a little more security.

Hope it helps.